# What would java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0) result in memory?

Tags: java, malloc, bytebuffer

Allocating zero-length buffer is normally implementation-dependent.
I know that `malloc(0)` returns either NULL or a pointer that can be safely freed, and this is totally implementation-dependent.

Then, what would happen when `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0)` is called?
(I mean, what would happen in the memory?)
Will this function allocate a small piece of memory like libc malloc() does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(int capacity)` returns `new DirectByteBuffer(capacity)` and `DirectByteBuffer(int capacity)` constructor allocates a memory of size `Math.max(1L, (long)capacity + (pa ? ps : 0));` where
'pa' is `VM.isDirectMemoryPageAligned()` and 'ps' is pagesize. You may follow line# 110 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.java#110

So, `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0)`creates memory of size at least 1.